# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory. Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installati

Tags: java, openjdk-21

please tell me how to solve this error

```
PS C:\Users\Александр Дайнека\IdeaProjects\Docker> ./mvnw clean package
```

> Error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
> JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin"
> Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
> location of your Java installation.

Initially, I was told that I had no way to java home at all. After that, I downloaded the latest version of java, installed it and set the path. After that, this error started to come out

Answer (score 4):

`JAVA_HOME` is the root directiory of the java installation:

```
set %JAVA_HOME%="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21"
```